# Unexpected code in synchronized block

Tags: java, jvm, jls

The following Java code generates the following JVM bytecode.

I'm curious why the code from offset 31 to offset 36 is generated. Nothing in the JLS7 or JVM7 specification talks about this. Did I miss anything?

Even if I remove the println statements, the code (offset 31 to offset 36) still get generated, only at an earlier location, since the println call has been removed.

```
// Java code
    void testMonitor() {
        Boolean x = new Boolean(false);
        synchronized(x) {
            System.out.println("inside synchronized");
            System.out.println("blah");
        };
        System.out.println("done");
    }


// JVM bytecode
    Offset  Instruction       Comments (Method: testMonitor)
    0       new 42            (java.lang.Boolean)
    3       dup
    4       iconst_0
    5       invokespecial 44  (java.lang.Boolean.<init>)
    8       astore_1          (java.lang.Boolean x)
    9       aload_1           (java.lang.Boolean x)
    10      dup
    11      astore_2
    12      monitorenter
    13      getstatic 15      (java.lang.System.out)
    16      ldc 47            (inside synchronized)
    18      invokevirtual 23  (java.io.PrintStream.println)
    21      getstatic 15      (java.lang.System.out)
    24      ldc 49            (blah)
    26      invokevirtual 23  (java.io.PrintStream.println)
    29      aload_2
    30      monitorexit
    31      goto 37
    34      aload_2
    35      monitorexit
    36      athrow
    37      getstatic 15      (java.lang.System.out)
    40      ldc 51            (done)
    42      invokevirtual 23  (java.io.PrintStream.println)
    45      return
```

Answer (score 7):

The compiler adds an invisible try/catch block here, to ensure the monitor state gets released (which is documented in the VM specs, see bottom of post). You can verify this by using `javap -v` and look at the exception table:

```
void testMonitor();
  Code:
   Stack=3, Locals=3, Args_size=1
   0:    new    #15; //class java/lang/Boolean
   3:    dup
   4:    iconst_0
   5:    invokespecial    #17; //Method java/lang/Boolean."<init>":(Z)V
   8:    astore_1
   9:    aload_1
   10:    dup
   11:    astore_2
   12:    monitorenter
   13:    getstatic    #20; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   16:    ldc    #26; //String inside synchronized
   18:    invokevirtual    #28; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   21:    getstatic    #20; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   24:    ldc    #34; //String blah
   26:    invokevirtual    #28; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   29:    aload_2
   30:    monitorexit
   31:    goto    37
   34:    aload_2
   35:    monitorexit
   36:    athrow
   37:    getstatic    #20; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   40:    ldc    #36; //String done
   42:    invokevirtual    #28; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   45:    return
  Exception table:
   from   to  target type
    13    31    34   any
    34    36    34   any
```

Edit: From the [JVM specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/Threads.doc.html#22500):

> Normally, a compiler for the Java programming language ensures that
>   the lock operation implemented by a monitorenter instruction executed
>   prior to the execution of the body of the synchronized statement is
>   matched by an unlock operation implemented by a monitorexit
>   instruction whenever the synchronized statement completes, whether
>   completion is normal or abrupt.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where it is in the JLS, but it must say somewhere that when an exception is thrown, a lock is released. You can do this with Unsafe.monitorEnter/Exit

```
void testMonitor() {
    Boolean x = new Boolean(false);
    theUnsafe.monitorEnter(x);
    try {
        System.out.println("inside synchronized");
        System.out.println("blah");
    } catch(Throwable t) {
        theUnsafe.monitorExit(x);
        throw t;
    };
    theUnsafe.monitorExit(x);
    System.out.println("done");
}
```

I believe there is a catch block table at the end you may be missing.

Comment: Hello Peter, your answer doesn't answer the question: "I'm curious why the code ... is generated" or even "Did I miss anything?". Thank you for your participation though.

Comment: The code is generated because there has to be code to release the lock, see my example. You missed my attempt to explain. ;)

Comment: Rene's explanation is better. Also, note that I didn't ask for an alternative way. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: It was to clarify exactly what is happening.  I assumed you might be more familar with java code than byte code.